# Unexpected output in PHP Post form

Tags: php

This is my index.php:

```
<?php
$about_me = array("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "Lorem ipsum");
?>
<form action="generate.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="about_me" value="<?php echo $about_me;?>">
<input type="submit" class="download_button" value="download">
</form>
```

This is generate.php:

```
<?php
$about_me = $_POST['about_me'];
$test = $about_me[0];
echo $test;
?>
```

The output of generate.php is

```
<
```

I expect the output to be **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.**.
But unexpectedly I am recieving just a arrow.
If someone can help me, I will be grateful.

Comment: You cant echo an array. That should be giving an error. You also have no element named `about me`.

Comment: Man, how many edits is this thing going to through? one being stealthy.

Comment: @chris85 thanks alot for pointing out.

Comment: You're trying to echo array into form fields, that is error in itself, first you shouldn't pass array in form field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot echo an array without an index.

So try this instead

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $about_me[0];?>">
//----------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

Also as you call this input field `name` i.e. `name="name"` use its name here

```
<?php
$about_me = $_POST['name'];
echo $about_me;
?>
```

> But remember this will only pass the first occurance of the `index.php`'s `$about_me` array.

If you want to pass all the data you added to the `$about_me` array, instead make it a simple string

```
<?php
$about_me = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,Lorem ipsum"
?>
<form action="generate.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="about_me" value="<?php echo $about_me;?>">
<input type="submit" class="download_button" value="download">
</form>
```

Or create as many hidden fields as there are occurances in your array

```
<?php
$about_me = array("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", 
                  "Lorem ipsum");
?>
<form action="generate.php" method="POST">
<?php
foreach ( $about_me as $me) :
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="about_me[]" value="<?php echo $me;?>">
<?php
endforeach;
?>
<input type="submit" class="download_button" value="download">
</form>
```

And then process like this

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['about_me']) {
        foreach ($_POST['about_me'] as $me) {
            echo $me . '<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Woops no data found';
?>
```

Comment: Alternative approach make `$about_me` a string.

Answer (score -2):

$_POST[] retrieves parameters from the form based on the parameters name. It has no access to any variables you may have set in your code (PHP or Javascript).

The parameter names are assigned from the elements of the form. I assume you are trying to get the value of the hidden input element, so you should check for $_POST['name'] instead of $_POST['about_me'].

Comment: There's no `GET` in this question.

Comment: Sorry, meant to write $_POST. Anyway I see that another answer was posted while I was writing mine which is more complete.